# Kafka fails to keep track of last-commited offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Is there any known issue with kakfa-broker in managing the offsets? Bcz, problem which we are facing is when we try to restart of kafka-consumer(i.e, app restart) sometimes all the offset are reset to 0. 
Completely clueless on why are consumers not able to start from the last commited offset.

We are eventually facing this issue in prod wherein the whole q events are replayed again :

- spring-boot version -- 2.2.6 release
- spring-kafka - 2.3.7 release
- kafka-client -2.3.1
- apache-kafka - kafka_2.12-2.3.1

We have 10 topics with 50 partitions for each topic which belongs to same group, we increase topic-partition and consumer count at run-time based on load.

- auto-commit = false
- sync commit each offset after processing
- max-poll-records is set to 1

After all this config it runs as expected in local setup, after deployed to prod we see such issues nut not at every restart.
Is there any config that i'm missing.
Completely Clueless!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not enable auto commit per the suggestion in another answer; the listener container will more reliably commit the offsets and, as you say, you don't have the problem all the time.

Is it possible that you receive no records for a week?

Or, is it possible that your broker has a shorter `offsets.retention.minutes` property?

In 2.0, it was changed from a 1 day default to 1 week. If the offsets have been removed because they expired and you restart the consumer, you'll get the behavior you observe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!! Correction @Gary, we are using "kafka_2.11-1.0.0" in prod. wherein  default value of offsets.retention.minutes is 1 day.
Can you please explain even if past offsets are expired, why is the offset getting reset to 0? Then in the replay we should not see expired recs...correct?
Another query, kafka client ->  2.3.1 and broker version  kafka_2.11-1.0.0" wont cause any problem in manual commiting offsets..

Comment: As per doc, offsets will get expired only when consumer group looses all its consumer 
[offsets.retention.minutes](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#offsets.retention.minutes) 
 **Need Clarificaltion plz**, _If the offsets expire and you restart the consumer before more records are received, there is no information on the broker about that consumer?_ By this you mean to say is if the lastCommitedOffset expires the new consumer which is up after restart will start to poll the offsets from 0(expired offsets as well) for particular partition which it has been assigned to by the broker.

Comment: Yes, my comment was wrong. Correction: It's not actually getting reset to 0. Kafka maintains the last committed offset for each consumer/partition. If the offsets expire because your consumer is offline for 24 hours, and restart the consumer, there is no information on the broker about that consumer, so it is considered a new consumer and if you have auto.offset.reset=earliest you will get everything again. With brokers before 2.0, you need to increase the retention time. No; using a 2.3 client against 1.0 is ok; but it would be better to move to a newer broker - the current is 2.5.0.

Comment: Some people hit this when, say, their application only runs on weekdays so it would always restart from the beginning on Monday. I think that was the motivation to increase it to a week.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, But our consumers are not been down for more than hour then too we are facing this issue of re-playing all the events from the start  again. Any suggestion how to tackle this problem? Will it be helpful to store the offset in external store (RDBMS)?

Comment: No; something else must be going on; the best place to store the offsets is Kafka itself. Interesting; the [1.0.0 documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation.html) has a very different description `Offsets older than this retention period will be discarded` - so maybe it was a different algorithm back then. The description was changed in 2.1.

Comment: YES - I just tested it with a 1.0.0 broker (with a 2 minute retention) and the offsets were removed as soon as I stopped the consumer (after I had waited 2 minutes with the consumer still running and receiving no records). With a 2.4.1 broker the offsets were not removed until 2 minutes elapsed after I stopped the consumer.

Comment: Okay - The main cause is still unidentified, By all this I understood is offsets will be removed only after all consumers of that group are inactive state  and offset  retention time is elapsed no matter which offset it is(either commited or uncommitted)....correct? I will try to update broker to 2.4.1 and see if the same issue occurs. Question - Can this issue occur due to abruptly shutting down of consumer application? If yes, please explain what happens internally that's makes Kafka to read from 0 position instead of lastcommitedoffset for all the partitions.

Comment: `>The main cause is still unidentified` Wrong. I told you I reproduced it. It's not clear to me why it's still not clear to you. With older brokers, it turns out the retention time is "time since last commit" so if the consumer is stopped, even briefly, after this time has elapsed, the offsets are removed. There is no such thing as "uncommitted offset". The broker persists the permitted offset and keeps the current "position" in consumer state in memory. If the time elapses, the commits are removed when you restart the consumer. Since there is no state, the initial position is 0.

Comment: It's actually worse than I thought; with a 1.0 broker, the offsets are removed even if the consumer(s) are still up. Not really a problem since the `position()` is still retained. However, if you have, say, two app instances sharing the partitions and the offset retention time elapses with no commits, the offsets are removed. If you then bring down one instance, a rebalance occurs and the records are all replayed on the remaining instance. This is not a problem with current brokers (tested with 2.4.1 and 2.5) because they are not removed until the consumers have been down that long.

Comment: Okay - Found the problem I guess when segments are rolled there seems to be unexpected behaviour on the kafka side due to which offsets were reset. 
[KAFKA-9543](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9543)
I wanted to know the cause of why is this happening?

Comment: That appears to be a bug in 2.4.0. I think I explained why it's happening; I won't participate further here.

Comment: No worries, Thanks @Gary for all your help. It seems there were multiple issues which we encountered with Kafka so far(for v1.0.0 and 2.4.1)                                                      Currupt Index, Segment Rolling and the one which you said Offset Retention. Will try to update the broker to 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that:

1) You are using the same Consumer Group ID

2) `auto.offset.reset` is set to `latest`

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=your-consumer-group-id
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=latest
```

---

In case you are still seeing this issue, try to enable auto-commit

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=true
```

and if the issue goes away then it means that your manual commits are not working as expected.